# Save Array of Key-Value pairs to MySQL-DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

For the Website on which I am currently working on I made a Form to add competences to a competences table but now I need to show, which department covers which competences how much.

My idea is, to add a Array of Key-Value pairs to each Department. For the Key I thought of using the custom competence-nr (e.g. A1.1) and for the Value an Integer of 0, 1 or 2 (not covered at all, partially covered, fully covered). How can I add a Key-Value Array to a table in Laravel and how can I make sure, that on each creation of a new competence it also gets added to each department.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: You can convert that array into a JSON string and then store that as text in DB field

Comment: I would recommend normalizing your tables. Have a "department_competence" table with columns: `competence_id, department_id, value` where you add a row per competence/department. Then you can do proper queries on that info.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson so you mean like a junction table because of the m:n relation?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am quite new to SO. Is there a way to mark a comment as a accepted answer?